# QTextBlockFormat.setLeftMargin(1em): How To?

Tags: html, qt, pyqt4

In a html-list with bullets, on change of the fontsize via format.setFontPointSize() the bullets drive out of the editor. I figured out the bullets stay on the same position on fontsize-change if I set the padding-left to 1em (tried this in a html-editor).
How can I achieve this for a list entry in Qt? Can I only set it to a pixel value and not to an element value?

```
        fmt=cur.charFormat()
        charSize=fmt.fontPointSize()
        if charSize==0.0:
            charSize=14
        if direction=="up":
            fmt.setFontPointSize(charSize+1)
            if textList:
                    blockFormat=cur.blockFormat()
                    #blockFormat.setLeftMargin(blockFormat.leftMargin()+0.4)
                    blockFormat.setLeftMargin(1em)
                    cur.mergeBlockFormat(blockFormat)
        else:
            fmt.setFontPointSize(charSize-1)
            if textList:
                    blockFormat=cur.blockFormat()
                    #blockFormat.setLeftMargin(blockFormat.leftMargin()-0.4)
                    blockFormat.setLeftMargin(1em)
                    cur.mergeBlockFormat(blockFormat)
        cur.mergeCharFormat(fmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default indentation for text lists in the QTextDocument instance that you are creating (I think the default is 40). Multiples of this value will be used for each indentation level in the list.

```
QTextDocument *doc = new QTextDocument();
doc->setIndentWidth(20);

QTextCursor *cursor = new QTextCursor(doc);

QTextListFormat listFormat;
listFormat.setIndent(1); // First indent level, indent is 20
cursor->insertList(listFormat);
// Insert items into the list

listFormat.setIndent(2); // Second indent level, indent is 40
cursor->insertList(listFormat);
// Insert nested list items
```

Comment: This does not affect my problem, as the bullets of the list are not within the indent. The "indented" letters start with the first letter after the bullet. So as their size increases, their position stays, but the bullet point moves to the left.